# How to build question answering program based on knowledge graph in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, knowledge-graph

I have a use case where, I have several word files. Currently I am extracting the text and storing it in Elasticsearch. From Elasticsearch, upon doing full phrase query,  I am only getting which page has the best score and its content. Now, I want to build a small run-time knowledge graph from the page content returned by Elasticsearch. And based on that knowledge graph I want to give specific answer to a particular question. Is it possible in python to build run-time knowledge graph and instantly give answer from that graph ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting your ElasticSearch to Neo4j. Neo4j provides python libraries as well. Do check those as well.

Read more here: https://neo4j.com/blog/knowledge-graph-search-elasticsearch-neo4j/

Comment: could you please elaborate more ? As of now I am getting the content of the best matched page from elasticsearch. Now how can I get the particular answer